# Convert CSV file to JSON with python

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I am trying to covert my CSV email list to a JSON format to mass email via API. This is my code thus far but am having trouble with the output. Nothing is outputting on my VS code editor.

```
import csv
import json


def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):

    data = {}

    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        for rows in csvReader:

            key = rows['No']
            data[key] = rows

    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


csvFilePath = r'/data/csv-leads.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'Names.json'

make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

Here is my desired JSON format

```
  {
        "EmailAddress": "hello@youngstowncoffeeseattle.com",
        "Name": "Youngstown Coffee",
        "ConsentToTrack": "Yes"
    },
```

Heres my CSV list

```
No,EmailAddress,ConsentToTrack
Zylberschtein's Delicatessen & Bakery,catering@zylberschtein.com,Yes
Youngstown Coffee,hello@youngstowncoffeeseattle.com,Yes
```

Comment: Please don't add links to images in your question. Just include an example of the CSV file, formatted as a code sample (just like your Python code).

Comment: Oh got it! Updated sample CSV list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could use a `csv.DictReader` to make this easier.

If I have `data.csv` that looks like this:

```
Name,EmailAddress,ConsentToTrack
Zylberschtein's Delicatessen,catering@zylberschtein.com,yes
Youngstown Coffee,hello@youngstowncoffeeseattle.com,yes
```

I can convert it into JSON like this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import json
>>> fd = open('data.csv')
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(fd)
>>> print(json.dumps(list(reader), indent=2))
[
  {
    "Name": "Zylberschtein's Delicatessen",
    "EmailAddress": "catering@zylberschtein.com",
    "ConsentToTrack": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Youngstown Coffee",
    "EmailAddress": "hello@youngstowncoffeeseattle.com",
    "ConsentToTrack": "yes"
  }
]
```

Here I've assumed the headers in the CSV can be used verbatim. I'll update this with an exmaple if you need to modify key names (e.g. convert "No" to "Name"),.

---

If you need to rename a column, it might look more like this:

```
import csv
import json


with open('data.csv') as fd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fd)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        row['Name'] = row.pop('No')
        data.append(row)

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Given this input:

```
No,EmailAddress,ConsentToTrack
Zylberschtein's Delicatessen,catering@zylberschtein.com,yes
Youngstown Coffee,hello@youngstowncoffeeseattle.com,yes
```

This will output:

```
[
  {
    "EmailAddress": "catering@zylberschtein.com",
    "ConsentToTrack": "yes",
    "Name": "Zylberschtein's Delicatessen"
  },
  {
    "EmailAddress": "hello@youngstowncoffeeseattle.com",
    "ConsentToTrack": "yes",
    "Name": "Youngstown Coffee"
  }
]
```

> and to print on my editor is it simply `print(json.dumps(list(reader), indent=2))`?

I'm not really familiar with your editor; `print` is how you generate console output in Python.

Comment: That would be great if you could list an example, and to print on my editor is it simply print(json.dumps(list(reader), indent=2)). ?